# How to set query parameters to url Angular2?

Tags: angular, query-string

I have a requirement to set a url with query parameters like `/Questions?id=1234&pageid=0`. I have tried to do it via `router.Navigate['/Questions?id=1234&pageid=0']` but no luck.

After navigation browser shows like `/Questions%3Fid%3D1234%26pageid%3D0`.

I have also tried it with setting `routerLink="/Questions?id=1234&pageid=0"`, but same result.

Please suggest any solution to do it.I am using **rc5** for **angular2**.

Comment: Check angular documentation for routing with query params : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#query-parameters

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found one solution by giving router-link and query-parameters separate, like below:

`<a [routerLink]="['/Questions']" [queryParams]="{id:1234,page:1}"></a>`

This is working fine for me.

Comment: Cheers! Been searching SO long for this. [Docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#query-parameters) seems wrong? But ofc - correct way hidden in the [cheatsheet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html)!

Answer (score 22):

You can pass them as item in the router, but outside the commands array:

`[routerLink]="["/Questions"], {queryParams: {id:1234, pageid:0}}"`

this generates what you want: `/Questions?id=1234&pageid=0`

Or you can use it programmaticaly:

`this.router.navigate(['/Questions'], { queryParams: {id:1234, pageid:0} })`

with router being an instance of `@angular/router`'s `Router`

Answer (score 6):

You can pass them as items in the router commands array:

```html
[routerLink]="['/Questions'] [queryParams]="{id:1234, pageid:0}} ]"
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#query-parameters

Comment: I am using it but it's giving me url like **/Questions;queryParams=%5Bobject%20Object%5D**.

Comment: For the root router optional parameters are represented in the querystring, for child routers they are added as matrix parameters (what you showed)

Comment: Yeah you are right, it's for child route. So, is there any solution to show query parameters for child routes rather than this matrix parameter?

Comment: Not as far as I know (except a custom route serializer) or maybe you can just add it to the root route.

Comment: Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your `router.navigate`

```
this.router.navigate(['/Questions', {id: 1234, pageid: 0}]);
```