# Angular 2 Routing adding query paramaters

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 2. I have an URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/#/briefcases/35/proposals
```

This URL is fine. But now I want to pass additional info with this URL. I want to add `SortOrder` and `SortBy`.

How do I accomplish this? What I want is something like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/#/briefcases/35/proposals?SortBy=Property&SortBy=Desc
```

How can I do this using `Router.Navigate`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set query parameters to url Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245848/how-to-set-query-parameters-to-url-angular2)

Answer (score 1):

You navigate to a route with query parameters using syntax something like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/proposals'], 
   { 
    queryParams: { sortBy: 'property', sortOrder: 'Desc' }
   }
);
```

I have a more complete example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing